# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher Windows 10 does not scan for beacons correctly

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10, beacon

I would like to scan for beacons periodically, for example every two seconds.
I tried to set the SamplingInterval of SignalStrengthFilter frequency, but it does not work.

So, i tried to implement this behaviour by myself using a Timer. I implemented a routine that collects beacons informations for two seconds and then it returns the list of beacons seen during this period. But it does not work correctly.

I use beacon that transmit every 0.5s and the scanner after two seconds does not see the correct number of beacons. Every time the number of beacons seen is variable.

I think that the problem is the scanning interval and the scanning window of Windows 10. 
Is there any way to adjust them?

This is the main code:

```
public void startDecoding()
{
        watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
        watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;          
        watcher.Start();

        t = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((t) =>
               {

                   timerCallback();
               }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));  //every two seconds for example

 }

private  void timerCallback()
{         
     List<Beacon> tmp;

     lock(_sync)
     {                    
         tmp = new List<iBeaconData>(beacons);
         beacons.Clear();
     }

     bc.onBeaconDetected(tmp);

 } 


private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{

        // The timestamp of the event
        DateTimeOffset timestamp = eventArgs.Timestamp;

        // The type of advertisement
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementType advertisementType = eventArgs.AdvertisementType;

        // The received signal strength indicator (RSSI)
        Int16 rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm;

        // The local name of the advertising device contained within the payload, if any
        string localName = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName;

        // Get iBeacon specific data
        var beaconData = eventArgs.Advertisement.iBeaconParseAdvertisement(eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm);


        if (beaconData == null)
            return;

        lock(_sync)
        {
            var existing = beacons.Where(b => b.UUID.ToString() == beaconData.UUID.ToString() && b.Major == beaconData.Major && b.Minor == beaconData.Minor).FirstOrDefault();


            if (existing != null)
            {
                 var idx = beacons.IndexOf(existing);
                 beacons.RemoveAt(idx);
            }

            beacons.AddSorted(beaconData);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: you are right, i added the main code

Comment: I am curious if you found away to get this done?